# Python selenium webdriver unable to click on Paytm "Log In/Sign Up"

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to locate and click on the Paytm "Log In/Sign Up" using

1. **Python 3.8.0**
2. **selenium 3.141.0**
3. **Chrome Version 83.0.4103.97 (Official Build) (64-bit)**

However, it seems that webdriver does find the element but somehow it does not click on it. Python code below works fine without any error. Also tried different locating techniques (commented in the the code) but no luck.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time


def syncClick(driver, timeout, locatorType, locator):
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((locatorType, locator))).click()
    except TimeoutError as e:
        print(e.args)

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get('https://paytm.com/')

# syncClick(driver, 10, By.XPATH, '//div[text()="Log In/Sign Up"]')
# syncClick(driver, 10, By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#app > div > div.R-WO > div._3AxU > div._3huM > div._1Vt1 > div')
syncClick(driver, 10, By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div._3ac-')

time.sleep(10)

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need wait until page perfect load. The element you mean appear first before other, so the javascript not yet ready to execute.

I've tried wait until `Digital Gold` text located before call your **`syncClick`** function.

```
driver.get('https://paytm.com/')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Digital Gold']")))

...
...

syncClick(driver, 20, By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div._3ac-')
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow! After inspecting the webpage's HTML code, I've deduced that the full XPATH for said button is `/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[4]/div`. You can use this XPATH data in the `.find_element_by_xpath()` function like so:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[4]/div")
```

Comment: Thanks @Xiddoc,but it does not help.

Answer (score 0):

you have to just wait a little bit to page load so add time.sleep(3) before the click action

```
time.sleep(3)
syncClick(driver, 10, By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div._3ac-')
```

Comment: Thanks, @Sibyl. I tried your suggestion but it does not help.

Comment: i tested your code and it works for me. maybe loading of page takes longer on you. can you try time.sleep(10) too?

Comment: I tried time.sleep(10) too but no luck. Same code works fine in Firefox and Edge. I am running  _Chrome 83.0.4103.**97** (Official Build) (64-bit), ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.**39**_. Could it be related to browser - driver compatibility?

Comment: i don't think so, i use same chrome with you but works fine for me. is it gives any error? or what happens? is it closes itself or doesnt do anything?

Answer (score 0):

To click on the link, one would have to use `time.sleep()` because the javascript takes time to get ready and explicit wait will not be working here that fine.
Try using this to find element by xpath:

```
//div[text()='Log In/Sign Up']
```

A snippet sample can be:

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='Log In/Sign Up']").click()
```